# Crypto NFC microchip: JavaCard or dedicated firmware?

Tags: nfc, javacard, ndef, ecdsa

I would like to implement some ECDSA functionalities into an NFC microchip (generating keypairs, signing, etc.), with NDEF communication.

I am wondering if JavaCards suits that need (size, power, protocol, performances, ECDSA acceleration, etc.), or if I'd rather use more dedicated hardware (e.g. banking secure element) with lower level software layer such as a dedicated firmware (the one I'm targeting is http://www.tiempo-secure.com/product/dual-interface-secure-chips/).

Thank you very much!

Mario.

Comment: If I read the SNEP standard correctly then NDEF is generally **not** used by smart cards; it is used between two NFC capable devices. Although many Java Cards can be read by NFC capable readers they generally just talk in "PICC" mode, where the act as a server that sends responds to commands using ISO 7816-4 defined APDU's. But besides the question if Java Card is *capable* to do ECDSA and key pair generation (which the API clearly is) your question if it suits your need requires an opinionated answer and is therefore off-topic IMHO.

Comment: Hello Maarten, thank you for your reply. I believe that NDEF is not only used for device-to-device as iOS only enables NDEF for NFC, and prevents sending data through it, so it cannot work for device-to-device. I believe they use it mainly for NDEF Smart Posters, which is a tag-to-device use case, therefore I believe that smart-cards can do NDEF. But my question was more specifically about JavaCards v.s. dedicated firmware. Thanks.

Comment: I think an NDEF tag is something different from a smart card CPU as used by e.g. banks. AFAIK Java Card doesn't do NDEF by itself, but a quick search shows a [library for Java Card](https://github.com/OpenJavaCard/openjavacard-ndef). However, that leaves us just with a comparison of two technologies that are capable of providing the same functionality; hence I voted this off topic.

Comment: Hello Maarten, yes Javacard can be implemented as tags, e.g. ST delivers then in wafers, which can then be flip-chiped into tags https://www.st.com/resource/en/data_brief/stpay-tigeriron.pdf

Comment: What makes that product better suited as a tag compared to the contactless solutions from NXP or Infineon, to name just two major manufacturers out there? Am I missing something? Flip chip contactless solutions are hardly new, right?